# Opening encrypted emails with c#

Tags: c#, email, outlook-addin, public-key-encryption

I'm working in Visual Studio 2012 to build a relatively simple add-in for Outlook 2010.  Machines are Win 7 Enterprise 32 and 64.  The purpose of the add-in is to decrypt email messages directly in the user's inbox so that they can be easily searched in .pst archives or saved to network folders as .msg files unencrypted.  The emails are encrypted using the x.509 PKI with the private keys stored on a smart card which prompts the user for a PIN each time an encrypted email is opened.  This is what I have so far:

```
private void buttonDecrypt_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)    {
  currentExplorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
  if (currentExplorer.Selection.Count > 0)      {
    for (int i = 0; i < currentExplorer.Selection.Count; i++)        {
      Object selObject = currentExplorer.Selection[i+1];
      if (selObject is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)          {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
          (selObject as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem);      
        mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003", 0);
        mailItem.Save();
      }                    
    }                
  }
}
```

If I manually open an encrypted email in Outlook, I get prompted for my PIN which allows the email to open fine.  Then if I close the email and hit my new button on the ribbon it does exactly what I want by re-saving the email unencrypted directly in my inbox.  However, if I select more than one email at once, or don't open the message manually first, my code errors on `mailItem.PropertyAccessor.Setproperty()` with message `COMException was unhandled by user code: Your Digital ID name cannot be found by the underlying security system.`  This tells me I need a way to prompt the user for their PIN prior to attempting to open the email.

Comment: No idea about your technical problem, but it seems to me that  `can be easily searched in .pst archives` is at odds with `prompts the user for a PIN each time an encrypted email is opened`

Comment: @PeterM correct.  If the email messages remain encrypted, the user is prompted for PIN each time the email is opened.  The email also gets skipped during outlook searches.  That is why I'm trying to add a button to re-save emails decrypted.  The purpose of the encryption is only for security during transmission.

Comment: @texasranger Well I don't know your use case but I suppose it really comes down to whether the encryption is required to protect the message only during transit, or also from nefarious co-workers.  But one C level guy losing his laptop sorta blows the encryption right out of the water :D

Comment: @PeterM The machines are secured by whole disk encryption.  The encrypted emails are used for communications outside the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is much you can do using the Outlook Object Model alone. OOM tries very hard to represent signed or encrypted messages as regular `IPM.Note` items. It goes as far as exposing a fake `IMessage` MAPI object from the `MailItem.MAPIOBJECT` property.

When you set the `PR_SECURITY_FLAGS` property, Outlook knows to decrypt the message. There is no way to specify how the decryption will be done or provide any parameters. That property is nothing but a hack to encrypt / decrypt Outlook messages; it only works when the property is set using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`.

Ultimately what you need is the data from the P7M attachment stored by the encrypted/signed message. You can see this in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author): if you click the IMessage button on the OutlookSpy toolbar (it uses `MailItem.MAPIOBJECT`), you will see the regular decrypted message. But if you click the IMAPISecureMesage in the IMessage window or open the message from the IMAPIFolder | GetContentsTable tab, you will see the raw encrypted message and its P7M attachment.

To extract that attachment, you will need either Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or a wrapper like [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author - use `RDOSession.GetMessageFromID`). Redemption also exposes the [RDOEncryptedMessage](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoencryptedmessage.htm) object that can be used for decryption .

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very informative.  That is a bit more involved than I'd like to deal with at the moment.  My solution for now is to add the decrypt button only to the "read" pane so that I know the user has already typed in the PIN to open the email.  Seems to work 100% for my small team, luckily this tool is only for internal use.